# Component not rendering latest data created when using <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is difference in React between writing url directly and using the below link.

Here is some code:

```
<Link onClick={() => history.push('/notification')}>My alerts</Link>
```

Here is the component that is redirected to when user click link my alerts.

```
const { data: employer, loading, error, refetch } = useQuery<Account>(AccountQuery)
  const [deleteSearchSubscription] = useMutation(DeleteSearchSubscriptionMutator, {
    onError: error => console.error(error),
    onCompleted: () => refetch(),
  })
```

UPDATE:

```
<Router>
        <Header />
        <Page>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/notification">
              <EmailNotifications />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/error-page">
              <PageNotFound />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/not-found">
              <ErrorPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login">
              <Login />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Page>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
```

any idea why when writing directly to url my component gets rendered with the latest data from backend while clicking on link it does not get the latest data from backend, why is this behavior?

Comment: That code looks fine, Can you share your routes?

Comment: UPDATED my question

Comment: do you call the AccountQuery somewhee else?

Comment: Did you check the data from backend really given back as you expected?

Comment: I do call it on some other component that has not to do with this one!

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 that's the problem backend does not give the latest data when redirecting with link, but it does when I type directly to url same /notification

Comment: so its like, only when i do hard refresh i receive latest data from backend!

Comment: @Lulzim are you redirecting to the same page?

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to see more of your code, but are you trying to refresh?
Because that link look good even I think this is better form

```
<Link to="/notification">My alerts</Link>
```

But if you are trying to reload and you are already on *yoursite.com/notification*, it will not work

But I cannot tell from the code you've provided if this is the case

If yes you need to redirect to other path and than back to /notification

**UPDATE:**

What Router do you use?

Basic Route component from React-router looks like this

```
<Route path="/notification" component={EmailNotifications} />
```

With no children

See: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component

Comment: tried with <Link to="/notification">My alerts</Link> same result, and I am ofc on some other view before i try to redirect!

Comment: It looks like you also use some weird router version, can you add your package.json content into your question?
Basic Route component looks like this 
<Route path="/notification" component={EmailNotifications} />
With no children

Comment: @AntonNémeth route does take children

Comment: From the same link you posted if you click basic you'll see the example.

Comment: Oh yeah @JuniusL. sorry but maybe thats the problem why it is not rendering right for Lulzim

Comment: The problem is not how  the route is defined it might be because react doesn't know that the values have changed.

Comment: i use "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",

Comment: that's sound right react does not know the changes, after redirecting using Link

Comment: @Lulzim try to use my suggestion with that 
<Route path="/notification" component={EmailNotifications} />

Comment: what does ```refersh()``` do?

Comment: The problem is here ```const { data: employer, loading, error, refetch }``` we don't know what is happening here,  which value does refresh update?, which value gets rendered by your component?. If you provide some info on those values we might help you.

Comment: @JuniusL. refetch() is used to make a call to backend, apollo stores results in cache, so refetch makes sure u are getting data from the database and not cache!

Answer (score 0):

Link has props `to`. So you don't need `onClick`

```
<Link to='/notification'>My alerts</Link>
```

Comment: still not working, same result as above after changing to <Link to='/notification'>My alerts</Link>

Answer (score 0):

adding:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    refetch()
  })
```

fixed the issue!

Comment: How?  Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.

Comment: it was intuitively! i know useEffect is called when component gets mounted so I thought lets refetch with latest data here in useEffect when component gets rendered and it apparently seems to work! I have no idea why react or apollo just didnt run the call to backend probably due some cache or idk. Refetch basically ignores cache